# How to preselect first item in md-sidenav

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I am trying to preselect the first item in my md-sidenav when the html is loaded. So I don't have to press the first button..
Did anybody already achieve this?

```
 <md-sidenav flex md-is-locked-open="$mdMedia('gt-sm')" md-component-id="left"
            class="sidenav md-whiteframe-z2 md-sidenav-left">
    <md-button ng-repeat-start="item in menuItems" layout="column" layout-align="center center"
               flex class="capitalize" ng-click="selectItem(item)"
               ui-sref="{{item.sref}}">
        <div class="md-tile-content">
            {{item.name}}
        </div>
    </md-button>
    <md-divider ng-repeat-end></md-divider>
</md-sidenav>
```

Controller is defined in the following way:

```
    menuItems = [
    {
        name: 'personA',
        icon: 'person',
        sref: '.personA'
    },
    {
        name: 'personB',
        icon: 'person',
        sref: '.personB'
    },
    {
        name: 'personC',
        icon: 'person',
        sref: '.personC'
    }
];

function toggleItemsList() {
    $mdSidenav('left').toggle();

}

function selectItem (item) {
    self.title = item.name;
    self.toggleItemsList();
}
```

Comment: Please add your controller logic.

Comment: done, any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that with `ng-init` and `$first`. Please take a look at this [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dora6bfm/).

```
<md-button ng-repeat-start="item in menuItems" 
           layout="column"  
           layout-align="center center"
           flex class="capitalize" 
           ng-click="selectItem(item)"
           ng-init="autoSelect($first, item)"
           ui-sref="{{item.sref}}">
  <div class="md-tile-content">
    {{item.name}}
  </div>
</md-button>
```

#### Scope function

```
$scope.autoSelect = function(first, item) {
  if (first) {
    self.title = item.name;
    self.toggleItemsList();
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Well, I can indeed find my first element in ng-repeat with $first, but for some reason it does not select that item so I don't get the detail view of my first item. I suppose it is about the ui-sref?

Comment: @Jymbo it does work as expected. Please take a look at the fiddle demo I included in my answer. Your problem is somewhere else. Btw. I used AngularJS $scopes to make it work. I dont know why you try to run it as self object defined functions.

Comment: thanks for the fiddle but that's unfortunately not what I've meant. I would like to literally select the first item (the same effect I would achieve if I would press the first button). What you are doing is just mapping the name of the first item in the md-content container...

Comment: @Jymbo I cant get you. Your button executes the function `selectItem()` with `ng-click`. The fiddle is executing exactly the same function but using scope params instead of object params. So where is the difference? Please create a fiddle or plnkr.

Comment: @Jymbo it does work fine like in the demo fiddle. Please check the demo fiddle. What is your problem?

Comment: it is working in the fiddle because your are just updating the $scope.title and then display it via "<h1 ng-bind="title"></h1>" . This is working in my code, as well. But I want to trigger the ui-router and then initially load a template into  "<div ui-view></div>". So I think I need to trigger ui-sref="{{item.sref}}" programmatically. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: @Jymbo If you going to create a new question, please write down your full requirements carefully. Link the new question here and I will help you.

Comment: Done, thanks. I would appreciate further help in this matter:

[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43699699/how-to-preset-state-of-ui-router-programmatically)