# How to preset state of ui-router programmatically

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-material

I have implemented an `md-sidenav` which allows to navigate to different html templates by selecting it in the sidenav list.
What I am trying is to preselect the first item in my `md-sidenav` when the whole html page is loaded. So I don't have to press the first button to get routed to the first template by ui-router.

**HTML:**

```
<md-sidenav flex class="sidenav md-whiteframe-z2 md-sidenav-left" md-component-id="left">
    <md-button ng-repeat-start="item in menuItems" 
               flex layout="column" layout-align="center center"
               ng-click="selectItem(item)"
               ui-sref="{{item.sref}}">
        <div class="md-tile-content">
            {{item.name}}
        </div>
    </md-button>
    <md-divider ng-repeat-end></md-divider>
</md-sidenav>

<md-content flex class="md-padding page-content">
    <div ui-view></div>
</md-content>
```

**Controller:**

```
menuItems = [
    {
        name: 'personA',
        icon: 'person',
        sref: '.personA'
    },
    {
        name: 'personB',
        icon: 'person',
        sref: '.personB'
    },
    {
        name: 'personC',
        icon: 'person',
        sref: '.personC'
    }
];

function toggleItemsList() {
    $mdSidenav('left').toggle();

}

function selectItem (item) {
    self.title = item.name;
    self.toggleItemsList();
}
```

**The stateProvider of ui-router:**

```
$stateProvider
    .state('.personA', {
        url:... 
        controller:... 
        templateUrl:... 
    })
    .state('.personB', {
        url: ...
        controller:... 
        templateUrl: ...
    })
    .state('.personC', {
        url: ...
        controller: ...
        templateUrl: ...
    });
```

I know the parameter of the first template by using `ng-init` and `$first` but for some reason the ui-router doesn't get triggered so no html template is loaded. I think I need to manipulate `ui-sref="{{item.sref}}"` but not sure about this.

Comment: Cheers m8, seems like The Bear did help ya right now =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To programmatically set a default state with ui-router you can use [$urlRouterProvider](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#urlrouterprovider):

`$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/yourDefaultStateUrl');`

Example:

```
function myConfig($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
    $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
        url: '/home', 
        templateUrl:... 
    })
    .state('about', {
        url: '/home', 
        templateUrl: ...
    });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home'); //Home as default state
}
```